# Start css animation without adding special class jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, slider

I am trying to improve my image/div slider, that runs on jQuery. Each slide is a DIV where any other tag can be added (text, image..). and has it's specific class with specific animation (so adding another class with jQuery for animation seems a bit more difficult, and I have at least 2 different sliders using same jQuery.. is there something to just say NOW to css (only for elements inside DIV)).

When I animate events on each slide (text coming from up etc.), they all start on page load - logically -, not on DIV that's currently in front. But with my current code I cannot apply CSS animation by adding another class to IMG, SPAN etc. since I have specific animation for each one, but jQuery does not recognize classes and just move DIVs to left/right.

How do I make jQuery (css probably not) to start this animations just on current showed DIV? I also want to let CSS animate it, not jQuery (`.animate()`) because I have already prepared long animations in CSS for it.

jQuery:

automatic slide:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#slider .some').ready(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 60000);
  });
```

and move right function

```
function moveRight() {
        $('#slider .some').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider .some div.slid:first-child').appendTo('#slider .some');
            $('#slider .some').css('left', '');
        });
    };
```

CSS: /*removed all unnecessary stuff */

```
.slid {
   /*width, height, overflow ... */
  }

img { -webkit-animation: frameFirst 2s ease-out;
      -moz-animation: frameFirst 2s ease-out;
      -o-animation: frameFirst 2s ease-out;
      animation: frameFirst 2s ease-out;
    }

span { -webkit-animation: frameSecond 2s ease-out;
      -moz-animation: frameSecond 2s ease-out;
      -o-animation: frameSecond 2s ease-out;
      animation: frameSecond 2s ease-out;
    }

    /* and  @keyframes for those animations */
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="some">
     <div class="slid">
         <span></span><!--TEXT STUFF, HAS ITS OWN ANIMATION-->
         <img /><!--IMAGE STUFF, HAS ITS OWN ANIMATION-->                                
      </div>
      <div class="slid">
         <!-- ANOTHER STUFF WITH ANOTHER ANIMATIONS -->                               
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `.filter()` to select specific elements.

Comment: Yeah, I can write it for tons of different classes, as I wrote, is there anything that would start all CSS inside current DIV (every single slide has same class) ?

Comment: `$(".className")` would select all elements with that `className`

Comment: It sounds like you want to begin the animation when a specific element is visible. Like if the User has to scroll down the page, the animation should start when that element is visible to the user. To do this, you'd want to fire the animation from within an event callback. Maybe when `.scrollTop()` has passed a specific value.

Comment: I think we're all talking about different stuff, I need to do that for every class INSIDE each '<div class="slid">', regardless the class names, so more suitable would be something like $(".slide .[some quantifier]") and then start all their css for those classes but then I don't know how to do it, without specifying every class [edit: not only DIV in front is visible, but also a bit of his left and right neighbor ]

Comment: What do all these classes have in common? Or you can use another attribute. For example: `$(".slid [class^='animate'])` would select all elements inside the `<div>` that have a class name beginning with "animate". But you have not provided a complete example, so it's not clear to the rest of us.

Comment: Yeah, something like this would work, but still, _. is there something to just say NOW to css (only for elements inside DIV)?_ as above, in question...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "now" and we already discussed how to select elements within another element. It might be best to setup a jsfiddle.net example.

Comment: Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/vyo2u06z/ a bit messy but basicaly, just let the second frame to do his animation after he will be in front

Comment: Cool, looking at it, I see that none of the classes are the same nor none of the elements. So you may want to select tham using `var slidItems = $(".slid").children();` This will give you all the elements within `.slid` regardless of their type. You can then use `.each()` to perform an animation on each one.

Comment: So, for example, `var slidItems = $(".slid").children();` and then `slidItems.each(function() { slidItems.addClass( "go" ); });` and now I can make `.somechild .go {animation}` .. ?

Comment: You can use `$(this)` inside `.each()` to target specific element. Example: `$('.slid').children().addClass("go");` will add 'go' to all child elements. You could then do `$(".go").each(function(){ $(this).animate(); });` And yes, that was what I was suggesting. Now one thing to note, you have a number of `.slid` elements, so you may want to look at iterating each of those and calling `.children()` on each of those.

Comment: Wow I got it working, thanks! Pity it's not written as up-vote able answer..

Comment: Glad to hear that. I posted an answer for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, you can use `.children()` and `.each()` to identify elements that do not have a lot in common.

For example, you can use:

```
$('.slid').children().addClass("go");
```

This will add the class "go" to all the children elements of class 'slid'. You can then use `.each()` to iterate each of those items.

```
$(".go").each(function(){
  $(this).animate();
});
```

In this, `$(this)` represents the individual element. If need you can also do:

```
$(".go").each(function(i, el){
  $(el).animate();
});
```

Where `i` is the Index (0, 1, 2, n...) of the element and `el` is the element itself.